# Use JSON.net Binder/TypeNameHandling for nested types

Tags: c#, json.net, asp.net-web-api2

Using JSON.net, I want to deserialize a list of types that inherit from an abstract class. I have used `KnownTypesBinder` ([source](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeSerializationBinder.htm)) like

```
var jsonSettings = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings;
jsonSettings.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto;
jsonSettings.Binder = new KnownTypesBinder { KnownTypes = new List<Type> { ... } };
```

**Now this works perfectly fine in the WEB API modelbinder;** `KnownTypesBinder.BindToType` is being called an the object can be deserialized. In a different part of the web application I have to deserialize a JSON string, so I would like to re-use the same JsonFormatter. According to the docs, the following should work;

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(String, JsonSerializerSettings);
```

However when I do just that:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<A>(jsonString, GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings);
```

The following error is thrown:

> JsonSerializationException. Could not create an instance of type C. Type is an interface or abstract class and cannot be instantiated.

My types look something like this;

```
class A {
    public B B { get; set; }
}

class B {
    public List<C> C { get; set; }
}

abstract class C { }

class C1: C { }
class C2: C { }
```

Also creating a new JsonSerializerSettings and setting `Binder` and `TypeNameHandling` makes no difference. I found that `KnownTypesBinder.BindToType` is not being called at all. Is there something in JSON.net that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Feeling stupid here. The discriminator used by JSON.net is called `"$type"`. As I was using `curl` to send the POST payload, bash tried to resolve `$type` to an environment variable. As there was no such variable, the final JSON was simply `{"": "C"}` instead of `{"$type": "C"}`.